# Can't play any videos in browsers on Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, firefox, video, streaming

I've installed Fedora 34 in VMware Workstation 16. Everything works smooth besides Wayland not outputting the right resolution. But today I have discovered that I can't play any videos inside Firefox. I have tried installing Brave and Waterfox browsers but still the same results: the videos are playing super super slow, almost not playing, and I have no audio, only some weird noises.
Also I have tried anything I could find on the internet on this topic - reinstalling firefox, disabling and enabling advanced features in firefox, installed the whole Multimedia group, enabled the `rpmfusion repos` and installed a bunch of plugins and codecs from there too, also I have restarted firefox in safemode and gave it a refresh, but nothing worked so far. Any ideas on how I could make this work?

Comment: Default (no mutimedia, no codecs) Fedora 34 - Mate  installed to hard disk : Firefox → Plays YouTube videos perfectly / perfect sound. ... Could be a wmWare / Wayland issue. Please try: Log out / Log in to X (Wayland X).

Comment: I switched to Arch, works 10 times smoother. I missed it so much. Thanks anyway, mate!